# Snakemake using multi inputs

Tags: python, pipeline, snakemake

I'm starting to write a pipeline for my bioinformatics project and I'm using the Snakemake as workflow.
I made all the tutorial of the official site and I some of the documentation.

I want to run a single shell command, like that:
`fastp -i input-1 -I input-2 -o output-1 -O output-2`

My code in Snakefile:

```
SAMPLES = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
rule fastp:
    input:
        reads1=expand("sample{sample}.R1.fq.gz", sample=SAMPLES),
        reads2=expand("sample{sample}.R2.fq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        reads1out=expand("sample{sample}.R1.fq.gz.out", sample=SAMPLES),
        reads2out=expand("sample{sample}.R2.fq.gz.out", sample=SAMPLES)
    shell:
        "fastp -i {input.reads1} -I {input.reads2} -o {output.reads1out} -O {output.reads2out}"
```

But the program run this single line of code:
`fastp -i sample1.R1.fq.gz sample2.R1.fq.gz sample3.R1.fq.gz sample4.R1.fq.gz -I sample1.R2.fq.gz sample2.R2.fq.gz sample3.R2.fq.gz sample4.R2.fq.gz -o sample1.R1.fq.gz.out sample2.R1.fq.gz.out sample3.R1.fq.gz.out sample4.R1.fq.gz.out -O sample1.R2.fq.gz.out sample2.R2.fq.gz.out sample3.R2.fq.gz.out sample4.R2.fq.gz.out`

How can I write the program to do a different shell command for each sample? I tried a `for i in SAMPLES:` after the `rule fastp:` but doesn't worked and I don't know what I can try now. Sorry if this topic is too basic in some way, but I'm a noob in Python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [define target](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) output files using `rule all`.

```
SAMPLES = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
rule all:
    input:
        expand("sample{sample}.R{read_no}.fq.gz.out", sample=SAMPLES, read_no=['1', '2'])

rule fastp:
    input:
        reads1="sample{sample}.R1.fq.gz",
        reads2="sample{sample}.R2.fq.gz"
    output:
        reads1out="sample{sample}.R1.fq.gz.out",
        reads2out="sample{sample}.R2.fq.gz.out"
    shell:
        "fastp -i {input.reads1} -I {input.reads2} -o {output.reads1out} -O {output.reads2out}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, JeeYem, but I still have the same problem. The snakemake still try to put all samples in a single line, as before.

Comment: Copy and paste my code and try again. Looks like you added `rule all` to your code but forgot to edit `rule fastp`.

Comment: Please add the final, working code if you can. This solution still generates a wildcards error.

Answer (score -1):

This is the output of command snakemake -np, with the `rule all:` , as JeeYem wrote:

`λ  fastp/testdata master ✗ snakemake -np
rule fastp:
    input: sample1.R1.fq.gz, sample2.R1.fq.gz, sample3.R1.fq.gz, sample4.R1.fq.gz, sample1.R2.fq.gz, sample2.R2.fq.gz, sample3.R2.fq.gz, sample4.R2.fq.gz
    output: sample1.R1.fq.gz.out, sample2.R1.fq.gz.out, sample3.R1.fq.gz.out, sample4.R1.fq.gz.out, sample1.R2.fq.gz.out, sample2.R2.fq.gz.out, sample3.R2.fq.gz.out, sample4.R2.fq.gz.out
    jobid: 1
fastp -i sample1.R1.fq.gz sample2.R1.fq.gz sample3.R1.fq.gz sample4.R1.fq.gz -I sample1.R2.fq.gz sample2.R2.fq.gz sample3.R2.fq.gz sample4.R2.fq.gz -o sample1.R1.fq.gz.out sample2.R1.fq.gz.out sample3.R1.fq.gz.out sample4.R1.fq.gz.out -O sample1.R2.fq.gz.out sample2.R2.fq.gz.out sample3.R2.fq.gz.out sample4.R2.fq.gz.out
localrule all:
    input: sample1.R1.fq.gz.out, sample1.R2.fq.gz.out, sample2.R1.fq.gz.out, sample2.R2.fq.gz.out, sample3.R1.fq.gz.out, sample3.R2.fq.gz.out, sample4.R1.fq.gz.out, sample4.R2.fq.gz.out
    jobid: 0
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   fastp
    2`

Comment: I would suggest to add this to your question. Answer section should be reserved for just answers.